# Using Env.js with Python

Tags: javascript, python, envjs

I am having a bit of difficulty getting Env.js working with my Python application. The documentation on the website states:

> develop bridges for running Envjs in Ruby, Python, and other host languages with the SpiderMonkey and V8 javascript engines

However, I have been unable to find any bridges to Python in either the main branch from github, or from Google.

Has anyone had any success getting Env.js working with Python?

Comment: So, did you in the end manage to find anything viable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, not sure where that text came from. I'm a committer on env.js and haven't heard of any integration efforts with python against V8 or SpiderMonkey.

Looks like NoseJS has some integration, but it doesn't look too general. Looks to be against the Rhino port of env.js with some tentative comments about using Python-Spidermonkey.

There is a port that uses SpiderMonkey via Ruby: http://github.com/smparkes/env-js.

Comment: The text came from: http://www.envjs.com/doc/guides

I need to emulate the DOM in Python. Know of any alternatives?

Comment: Ah ... yeah. Sorry. I know where the text is written, I'm just not certain who wrote it. I think you'd have to call it a bit of hyperbole/vision.

I don't know of any existing alternatives. I wonder if jython could work. It's challenging to combine two garbage-collected runtimes: that's one of the bigger challenges/limitations in the Ruby-hosted SpiderMonkey port. Using Java lets you just use the JVM GC and maybe use all/most of the Rhino port? BUt I haven't kept up on the status of jython ...

Comment: Do I understand correctly that all that there is to it is implementing all of the functions in the "platform" section: http://www.envjs.com/doc/apis ?

Do you know of any resources that would describe these functions in greater detail? What would you use as a reference? I'm mainly interested in AJAX related stuff.

Comment: Bump. It doesn't look that hard to implement the stuff in the "platform" section of envjs.com/doc/apis. It just seems nobody has done that, as far as I have found. I too would appreciate more info on this.